# CASE with regexp: "set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set"

Tags: regex, postgresql, postgresql-9.0, set-returning-functions

I'm trying to do a slightly complicated string conversion in PostgreSQL 9.0.1. The values in `my_col` are long strings in the format of:

```
'12345_sometext_X12B_1'
'12345_sometext_optionaltext_Y09B_1'
'12345_sometext_optionaltext_X12A_1'
```

I need to translate the 'X12' portion to a known numeric value, there are a few different known values (up to 5).

I expect to be able to determine this within one query without needing a subquery. However, the following isn't working for me. The last column is the one throwing the exception. It seems I cannot do the `CASE` statement using the output of these functions combined for some reason. I've included the proceeding columns for demonstrational purposes only.

```
select
          regexp_matches(my_col, E'^.*_([^_]*)[A-Z]{1}_\\d*$'), -- returns {'X12'}
         (regexp_matches(my_col, E'^.*_([^_]*)[A-Z]{1}_\\d*$'))[1], -- returns 'X12'
    case (regexp_matches(my_col, E'^.*_([^_]*)[A-Z]{1}_\\d*$'))[1]
        when 'X12' then '1200'
        when 'Y09' then '950'
        else '?' end -- should return '1200' but throws error
from my_table;
```

Instead I get the error:

```
ERROR: set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set
SQL state: 0A000
```

Can someone advise me?

Comment: First: Update, you're on an obsolete version. Upgrade to 9.0.10 for bugfixes, security and stability improvements. No dump and reload is required, just install the new binaries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given data:

```
create table my_table(my_col text);
insert into my_table(my_col) values
('12345_sometext_X12B_1'),
('12345_sometext_optionaltext_Y09B_1'),
('12345_sometext_optionaltext_X12A_1'),
('nomatch');
```

the above query does produce the error you report. Very odd, since:

```
SELECT pg_typeof((regexp_matches(my_col, E'^.*_([^_]*)[A-Z]{1}_\\d*$'))[1]);
```

returns 'text'. It should really say `setof text` though, and that's the trap: `regex_matches` is a set returning function. Those have ... interesting ... behaviour when called outside the FROM clause in PostgreSQL.

From [pattern matching](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html):

> The regexp_matches function returns a text array of all of the
>   captured substrings resulting from matching a POSIX regular expression
>   pattern. It has the syntax regexp_matches(string, pattern [, flags ]).
>   The function can return no rows, one row, or multiple rows

Try reformulating your query to use a subquery to call the SRF. This'll fail if more than one row is returned by the matcher, though:

```
SELECT 
  CASE (SELECT x[1] FROM regexp_matches(my_col, E'^.*_([^_]*)[A-Z]{1}_\\d*$') x)
    WHEN 'X12' THEN '1200'
    WHEN 'Y09' THEN '950'
    ELSE '?'
  END
FROM my_table;
```

---

Want to see how weird SRFs in SELECT are in Pg? Compare the results of these queries:

```
SELECT generate_series(1,10), generate_series(1,15);
```

and:

```
SELECT generate_series(1,10), generate_series(1,20);
```

The 1st produces 30 rows. The 2nd produces 20. Have fun explaining why. More than one SRF in a SELECT list in Pg produces crazy if occasionally useful results.

PostgreSQL 9.3 supports the SQL-standard `LATERAL` clause thanks to Tom Lane, which provides a sane and well defined alternative to the current behaviour.

Comment: Incrementally changing the arguments to `generate_series()` is horrifying by seeing the number of rows change.

Comment: @cpburnz ... and the completely nonsensical way it works? Yep. That's why I use `LATERAL`, never set-returning functions in the `SELECT` list.

Answer (score 2):

[**`regexp_matches()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) returns `SETOF text[]` (a ***set of text arrays***), which is useful for multiple matches for one pattern in the same string. But it is simply the **wrong tool** for this task.

Use [**`substring()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) with a regular expression instead. It returns `text`. Reusing the [demo table in @Craig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12796491/939860):

```
SELECT CASE substring(my_col, '^.*_([^_]*)[A-Z]_\d*$')
         WHEN 'X12' THEN '1200'
         WHEN 'Y09' THEN '950'
         ELSE            '?'
       END As result
FROM   my_table;
```

Returns:

```
 result
--------
 1200
 950
 1200
 ?
```

Also slightly simplified the regular expression. `{1}` was just noise.

If you need to optimize **performance** try to make do without regular expressions, which are powerful but comparatively expensive. Something like:

```
reverse(right(split_part(reverse(my_col), '_', 2), -1))
```

Looks more complex, but is still faster in my tests.

Comment: For whatever reason `substring` has significantly worse performance here (although it does solve my particular issue, which is the same as the above).

Your answer is missing that the question includes the array indexer: `regexp_matches(src, regex)[1]`.

Comment: @RhysvanderWaerden: That reason would be interesting, I cannot reproduce it. `substring()` is faster in my tests (as expected.) And why would the answer be missing anything about the array index? The SRF is invalid where it's used, with or without array index. I updated a bit and added an even faster alternative.